# In Elasticsearch, how do I perform a nested sum query with a filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a mapping as follows:

```
PUT cars
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "_doc":{  
         "properties":{  
            "metadata":{  
               "type":"nested"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I insert a document:

```
PUT /cars/_doc/1
{  
   "metadata":[  
      {  
         "key":"price",
         "value":20000
      },
      {  
         "key":"miles",
         "value":1000
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I wish to retrieve the sum of all the prices (there's only one document here but I still think it's enough to show the point).

I've tried:

```
GET cars/_doc/_search

{
  "aggs": {
    "metadata": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "metadata"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "prices": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "metadata.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this will includes `miles`, which I don't want.

How do I add a filter so that only `price` is included in my query ie how do I get the query to return 20,000, not 21,000?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to consider only price, all you need to do is filter the nested documents where `key` is `price`. To do this you need to add [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) as below:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "metadata": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "metadata"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "price": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "metadata.key": "price"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "prices": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "metadata.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Hoa : Was the answer useful and solved your problem?